# How do I remove 'Scan selected files with Avira' from the context menu?

Tags: context-menu

Please see screenshots below. Why doesn't 'avira' appear in ShellExView or ShellMenuView?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Registry Editor:

[image]

2. Delete the key named "Shell Extension for Malware scanning"

[image]

3. Click "Yes"

[image]

The Avira context menu entry has now been removed:

[image]

Comment: It doens't work in Windows 10 in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

If the installation of Avira is in a bad shape, you might uninstall it and
scrub the registry. After that, if required, you may reinstall it with the
proper settings.

To completely uninstall Avira:

- Uninstall Avira from *Control Panel > Programs and Features* and reboot
- Make sure that Folder Options are set as follows:
  *Start > Control Panel > Folder Options > View > Show Hidden Files and Folders > OK*
- Ensure the following folders no longer exist, and delete if not:

  ```
    C:\Program Files\Avira
    C:\ProgramData\Avira
    C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Avira
    C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Avira
    C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AviraWebView2Cache
  ```
- Download and run the
  [Avira RegistryCleaner](https://www.avira.com/en/download-start/product/avira-registry-cleaner),
  click *Read Keys* and confirm with *OK* after the scan.
  If any keys are found, enable the control box "Select all", and click *Delete*,
  finally confirm with *OK*.
- Reboot.

Comment: Let's add 
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Avira
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AviraWebView2Cache

 to the list.

Comment: @westman379: Done.